# Extracting URL from HTML in python

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to obtain a list containing different url that appear (partially) when you see the HTML version of this webpage:

https://www.renfe.com/es/es/cercanias/cercanias-valencia/lineas

I have tried a couple of different things, yet they don't really work.

**First attempt**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import html
import urllib
import json
import re

url = 'https://www.renfe.com/es/es/cercanias/cercanias-valencia/lineas'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "rftabdetailline accordion aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--default--12")
```

*links* contains the following:

```
 [<div class="rftabdetailline accordion aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--default--12">
 <!-- rf-tab-detail-line en resto de modos -->
 <rf-tab-detail-line content='[{"color":"120,180,225","name":"C1","active":"true","stations":"València Nord \u2013 Gandía","url":"/content/renfe/es/es/cercanias/cercanias-valencia/lineas/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/rftabdetailline/item_1.html"},{"color":"245,150,40","name":"C2","active":"false","stations":"València Nord \u2013 Xàtiva \u2013 Moixent","url":"/content/renfe/es/es/cercanias/cercanias-valencia/lineas/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/rftabdetailline/item_1591014181985.html"},{"color":"125,37,130","name":"C3","active":"false","stations":"València Sant Isidre \u2013 Buñol \u2013 Utiel","url":"/content/renfe/es/es/cercanias/cercanias-valencia/lineas/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/rftabdetailline/item_1591014184209.html"},{"color":"215,0,30","name":"C4","active":"false","stations":"València Sant Isidre \u2013 Xirivella L\u2019Alter","url":"/content/renfe/es/es/cercanias/cercanias-valencia/lineas/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/rftabdetailline/item_1591014185974.html"},{"color":"0,139,41","name":"C5","active":"false","stations":"València Nord \u2013 Caudiel","url":"/content/renfe/es/es/cercanias/cercanias-valencia/lineas/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/rftabdetailline/item_1591014187588.html"},{"color":"15,50,135","name":"C6","active":"false","stations":"València Nord \u2013 Castelló","url":"/content/renfe/es/es/cercanias/cercanias-valencia/lineas/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/rftabdetailline/item_1591014189921.html"},{"color":"150,100,40","name":"ER02","active":"false","stations":"Castelló - Vinaròs","url":"/content/renfe/es/es/cercanias/cercanias-valencia/lineas/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/rftabdetailline/item_1598612779629.html"}]' title-text="Seleccione una línea:">
 </rf-tab-detail-line>
 </div>]
```

In it, you can see the pieces that I want: for example, * "url":"/content/renfe/es/es/cercanias/cercanias-valencia/lineas/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/rftabdetailline/item_1.html" *. I would like to obtain all the different **/content/renfe/es/es/cercanias/cercanias-valencia/lineas/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/rftabdetailline/item_WHATEVER.html** in a list. In order to do so, I have tried an extract and using regular expressions, but I have not been succesful.

**Second Attempt**

Following the steps that are shown in the answer to this question
[Extractinf info form HTML that has no tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70486074/extractinf-info-form-html-that-has-no-tags)
I obtained the next piece of code:

```
import requests
import html
import json

url = 'https://www.renfe.com/content/renfe/es/es/cercanias/cercanias-valencia/lineas'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text  # get data from site
raw_list = data.split("'")[8]  # extract attributes
json_list = html.unescape(raw_list)  # decode html symbols
parsed_list = json.loads(json_list)  # parse json
```

I thought that it would work because of the similarities in the output it produces, but when defining parsed_list the next error is returned:

- **JSONDecodeError**: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)*

Does anyone have anythoughts?
Thank you all in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would instead use a css attribute = value selector to target the single element housing that data as it is more intuitive upon reading. Then you simply need to extract the `content` attribute and handle with `json` library filtering for the `url` key value pairs.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.renfe.com/es/es/cercanias/cercanias-valencia/lineas'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('[title-text="Seleccione una línea:"]')['content'])
links = [i['url'] for i in data]
```